# How to return new page after PHP progress updates

Tags: php

I have a long running script that produces feecback to the browser using the following code:

```
private function send_import_response($response, $add_linefeed = true) {

        ob_implicit_flush(true);
        echo $response;
            if ($add_linefeed) echo '<br/>';
            for($k = 0; $k < 40000; $k++)
                echo ' '; // extra spaces to fill up browser buffer

    }
```

This works fine. However, once the process is finished, the feedback is left at the top of the page and the HTML is below that.

How can I clear the text from the progress feedback before the HTML of the new page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd listen to the $response via JS/Ajax, and then when the response is right(or when the number of responses is right), I'd refresh the page. I am not sure if it will work solely with PHP; at least I've never tried it myself.

Comment: You know, I considered that idea. But I was not sure if AJAX could read these responses from the PHP. I suppose if I don't get a solution, I will give it a try.

Comment: Of course it can, and it is much more easier, and less hacky (read: more reliable).